# Dynamic mime mapping Wildfly / Undertow

Tags: java, wildfly, undertow

I would like to serve static content. I have configured undertow as Wildfly 10 subsystem. And it works. But it dosent serv mime type in http header. I know that I can use mime mapping, file extension - mime type. But i have mime types in database and files with no extension. Any ideas ?

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" max-post-size="1048576000" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <location name="/App/media" handler="media"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        <file name="media" path="/home/deployers/media-data"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```